# Assigning data in a field to another field based on day of week

Tags: ms-access

I am creating an Access database that is taking an imported CSV file, stripping out unnecessary columns, and leaving the entries for [**Date, Staff Name,** and **Decimal Hours** (time worked)] in an imported database "[tblTimesheetImport]".

I created a table "[tblTimesheet]" that has the following fields:

[Date] [Staff Name] [Monday] [Tuesday] [Wednesday] ... [Sunday]

The issue I am running into is figuring out how to get the **Decimal Hours** entries I have in the imported table to populate the days in [tblTimesheet] based on the day of the week pulled from the [Date] field. I formatted the [tblTimesheetImport] to a Long Date with the day of the week showing, since the imported CSV has the date logged for the Staff Name as well as their decimal hours, but I am having trouble figuring out how I could get those hours to be inserted into the Day of the Week fields listed above based on the date.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Why is there a date field in your table? Is that for the week number/year? Or do you want 6 of the 7 days per record to be blank?

Comment: Basically, the staff at a location uses a program to record their time each day. So the date field is essentially a date stamp. These people will more than likely be working multiple days, so to answer your second question - all those dates will be filled in with the hours worked for each person.

Haven't figured out that part just yet, but I believe it would need to Group By on each person's name so it wouldn't make a separate entry with the same person's name for a different day.

Comment: So the timestamp will be updated when they enter the next day's hours, and you only will have data for the current week?

Comment: Are you talking about the WeekDayName function, which returns the name of the day, and thus allow you to match to your column name?  Basically if WeekdayName = FieldName then put the hours in that field.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Yeah, the staff enter each day's hours in and then I export that data through the website at the end of the week as a .CSV file. I use that .CSV file I exported to feed into a table named tblTimesheetImport. The export contains the Date, Staff Name, and Hours Worked. At the end of the week, it is very possible that one individual worked 6.5 hours on Monday, 4 hours on Tuesday, etc.

Comment: @geeFlo I'll give that a shot! I will let you know if that works out.